# Why do FragmentPagerAdapter create 2 fragments at the same time?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I used the wizard to create an tabbed Activity which contains an FragmentPagerAdapter, in the getItem() function I tried to return my own fragments as follows:
[image: overriden getItem()]

However when the App runs and the view is in the first tab, I found it actually goes through the onCreateView() function in both **Fragment** and **Fragment2**(known from println() in onCreate() & onCreateView()), and when I swipe to Fragment2, it prints **Fragment3**. and when swipe to Fragment3, it prints **nothing**.. and after that I swipe back to Fragment2, It prints **Fragment1**.
What's wrong with it?

[image: when the app starts it reveals both fragment1 and 2's oncreate()]

Comment: @drunkpiano: Have you read the documentation? Thats how it works

Comment: @MD no need of break as in each case something is `return`ed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats is how a FragmentPagerAdapter is supposed to work. It created the Fragment in selected position and also the previous position and next position. This is so that when you move from one fragment to another through swipe the next fragment is ready so that it can be animated into the view. You can read about it below.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html